# Change podcast show using Siri

Tags: siri, podcasts

I'd like to tell Siri change a show while listening to podcasts, while already playing.

Tried many queries like "Change podcast show", "Skip this episode", "Next" and many more, some of them leads to google search, some search the apple music library for some reason and some of them are answered by "Sorry, I couldn't skip this".

Any ideas what command could help me achieveing this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

[Apple provides a list of commands](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208279) that can be used for the Podcast app.  If the command isn't listed here it's probably not going to work with the Apple app.  Third-party apps can use Shortcuts to have Siri perform more tasks so be sure to check with the developer if you use one of those.

### Play and subscribe to podcasts

Play your favorite podcast, listen to a new podcast, and subscribe to podcasts. Say "Hey Siri," then say something like:

- "Play The Rubin Report."
- "Play the latest episode of The Ben Shapiro podcast."
- "What podcast is this?"
- "Subscribe to this show."

### Control playback

Ask Siri to control playback of a podcast that you're listening to. Just say "Hey Siri," then you can say things like:

- "Pause."
- "Jump back 30 seconds."
- "Play it twice as fast."
- "Skip ahead 10 minutes."